# WSO2 BAM - How to configure BAM to force hive ExecDriver to use a different java_home from the environment variable set on windows?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I've installed BAM as Windows Service with yajsw. 
I've set a different java_home from the one that is configured at windows environment variable at wrapper config.

At BAM startup I can verify that this configuration is taking effect;

```
{org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Home: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_35 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
```

But whtn Hive ExecDriver runs uses java_home of the windows environment variable:

```
{org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jrockit-jdk1.6.0_20-R28.1.0-4.0.1\bin\java...
```

How can i force Hive to use BAM java_home?